# Repeating copy/paste steps in specify sheets - how can I simplify my VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am beginner in VBA and I would like to ask someone of more experienced folks to simplify my VBA code.

The code works really simple. Macro goes through drill-down list of sourcing .xlsx files, refresh table as PowerQuery result every time drill-down reference is set by loop (sheet "CZDataSource") and do same repeating copy/paste steps in each three sheets of the same workbook (sheets "Forecast - Month", "Forecast - Month +1", "Forecast - Month +2").

```
Sub SpitValues()

Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
'Drop-down list source
Set dvCell = Worksheets("CZDataSource").Range("C3")
Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

For Each c In inputRange
 dvCell = c.Value
 
 If (Right(Range("C2"), 3) = "1st") And Range("C3") = "RIG Forecast_2021_act.xlsx" Then
      Sheets("CZDataSource").ListObjects("RIG_Forecast_output").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      'CZ data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C7:C12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("AZ34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("AZ34:AZ39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D7:D12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BA34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BA34:BA39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BB34:BB39").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F7:F12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BI34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BI34:BI39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G7:G12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BJ34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BJ34:BJ39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BK34:BK39").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E7:E12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BO34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BO34:BO39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BP34:BP39").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H7:H12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BS34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BS34:BS39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BT34:BT39").Value = "0"
      'SK data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C13:C18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("AZ55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("AZ55:AZ60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D13:D18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BA55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BA55:BA60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BB55:BB60").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F13:F18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BI55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BI55:BI60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G13:G18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BJ55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BJ55:BJ60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BK55:BK60").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E13:E18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BO55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BO55:BO60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BP55:BP60").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H13:H18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BS55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BS55:BS60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BT55:BT60").Value = "0"
 
 ElseIf (Right(Range("C2"), 3) = "1st") And Range("C3") = "RIG Forecast_2021_m+1.xlsx" Then
      Sheets("CZDataSource").ListObjects("RIG_Forecast_output").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        'CZ data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C7:C12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("AZ34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("AZ34:AZ39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D7:D12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BA34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BA34:BA39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BB34:BB39").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F7:F12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BI34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BI34:BI39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G7:G12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BJ34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BJ34:BJ39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BK34:BK39").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E7:E12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BO34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BO34:BO39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BP34:BP39").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H7:H12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BS34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BS34:BS39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BT34:BT39").Value = "0"
      'SK data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C13:C18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("AZ55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("AZ55:AZ60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D13:D18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BA55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BA55:BA60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BB55:BB60").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F13:F18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BI55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BI55:BI60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G13:G18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BJ55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BJ55:BJ60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BK55:BK60").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E13:E18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BO55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BO55:BO60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BP55:BP60").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H13:H18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BS55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BS55:BS60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BT55:BT60").Value = "0"
 
 ElseIf (Right(Range("C2"), 3) = "1st") And Range("C3") = "RIG Forecast_2021_m+2.xlsx" Then
      Sheets("CZDataSource").ListObjects("RIG_Forecast_output").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     'CZ data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C7:C12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("AZ34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("AZ34:AZ39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D7:D12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BA34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BA34:BA39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BB34:BB39").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F7:F12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BI34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BI34:BI39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G7:G12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BJ34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BJ34:BJ39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BK34:BK39").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E7:E12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BO34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BO34:BO39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BP34:BP39").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H7:H12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BS34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BS34:BS39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BT34:BT39").Value = "0"
      'SK data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C13:C18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("AZ55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("AZ55:AZ60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D13:D18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BA55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BA55:BA60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BB55:BB60").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F13:F18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BI55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BI55:BI60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G13:G18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BJ55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BJ55:BJ60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BK55:BK60").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E13:E18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BO55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BO55:BO60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BP55:BP60").Value = "0"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H13:H18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BS55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BS55:BS60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BT55:BT60").Value = "0"
 
 ElseIf (Right(Range("C2"), 3) = "2nd") And Range("C3") = "RIG Forecast_2021_act.xlsx" Then
      Sheets("CZDataSource").ListObjects("RIG_Forecast_output").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      'CZ data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C7:C12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("AZ34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("AZ34:AZ39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D7:D12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BB34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BB34:BB39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F7:F12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BI34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BI34:BI39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G7:G12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BK34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BK34:BK39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E7:E12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BP34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BP34:BP39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H7:H12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BT34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BT34:BT39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      'SK data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C13:C18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("AZ55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("AZ55:AZ60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D13:D18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BB55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BB55:BB60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F13:F18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BI55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BI55:BI60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G13:G18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BK55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BK55:BK60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E13:E18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BP55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BP55:BP60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H13:H18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BT55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month").Range("BT55:BT60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
    
 ElseIf (Right(Range("C2"), 3) = "2nd") And Range("C3") = "RIG Forecast_2021_m+1.xlsx" Then
      Sheets("CZDataSource").ListObjects("RIG_Forecast_output").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      'CZ data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C7:C12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("AZ34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("AZ34:AZ39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D7:D12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BB34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BB34:BB39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F7:F12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BI34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BI34:BI39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G7:G12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BK34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BK34:BK39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E7:E12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BP34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BP34:BP39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H7:H12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BT34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BT34:BT39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      'SK data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C13:C18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("AZ55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("AZ55:AZ60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D13:D18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BB55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BB55:BB60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F13:F18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BI55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BI55:BI60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G13:G18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BK55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BK55:BK60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E13:E18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BP55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BP55:BP60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H13:H18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BT55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +1").Range("BT55:BT60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"

 ElseIf (Right(Range("C2"), 3) = "2nd") And Range("C3") = "RIG Forecast_2021_m+2.xlsx" Then
      Sheets("CZDataSource").ListObjects("RIG_Forecast_output").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
      'CZ data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C7:C12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("AZ34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("AZ34:AZ39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D7:D12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BB34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BB34:BB39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F7:F12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BI34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BI34:BI39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G7:G12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BK34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BK34:BK39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E7:E12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BP34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BP34:BP39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H7:H12").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BT34").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BT34:BT39").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      'SK data input/output
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("C13:C18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("AZ55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("AZ55:AZ60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("D13:D18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BB55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BB55:BB60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("F13:F18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BI55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BI55:BI60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("G13:G18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BK55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BK55:BK60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("E13:E18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BP55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BP55:BP60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
      Sheets("CZDataSource").Range("H13:H18").Copy
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BT55").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, operation:=xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
      Sheets("Forecast - Month +2").Range("BT55:BT60").NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
    
    Else
        
        MsgBox ("there is something wrong")
    
    End If
    
Next c

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Basically, I would like to get rid of so many repeating steps in particular sheets and cut short and simplify the code.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thumb up - that's the right question to become better in programming :-). Some quick ideas (maybe I have time later to write a full answer): create a mapping-array that maps source-cells/addresses to target-cells/address, have a generic function for the copy/paste stuff, as parameters you pass the source/target-cell-address from your array, use .value = .value to instead of copy/paste (you will find tutorials about this), use variables for your sheets etc.

Comment: My immediate thought it a function and pass the ranges, e.g., `DoTheThing(Range1,Range2,Range3)` where `DoTheThing()` outlines the copy/paste.  Since you're doing the same thing over and over, and only determing the sheet, set the sheet in a `Select` case, then perform the copy paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your ranges into arrays and then you can loop through them re-using the same code lines.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub SpitValues()

    Const PREFIX = "RIG Forecast_2021_"

    Dim dvCell As Range, inputRange As Range, c As Range
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    
    'Drop-down list source
    Set wsSrc = Sheets("CZDataSource")
    Set dvCell = wsSrc.Range("C3")
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)
    Set tbl = wsSrc.ListObjects("RIG_Forecast_output")
    
    ' put source ranges into array
    Dim arSrc, arTgt, arZeros, i As Integer, bError As Boolean, s As String
    arSrc = Split("C,D,E,F,G,H", ",")
      
    ' put target and zero ranges for 1st/2nd into arrays
    s = Right(wsSrc.Range("C2"), 3)
    If s = "1st" Then
        arTgt = Split("AZ,BA,BO,BI,BJ,BS", ",")
        arZeros = Split("BB,BP,BK,BT", ",")
    ElseIf s = "2nd" Then
        arTgt = Split("AZ,BB,BP,BI,BK,BT", ",")
        arZeros = Array()
    Else
        MsgBox "'" & s & "' is not 1st/2nd in C2", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' copy source to target
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each c In inputRange
        dvCell.Value = c.Value

        ' select target sheet
        If c.Value = PREFIX & "act.xlsx" Then
            Set wsTarget = Sheets("Forecast - Month")
        ElseIf c.Value = PREFIX & "m+1.xlsx" Then
            Set wsTarget = Sheets("Forecast - Month +1")
        ElseIf c.Value = PREFIX & "m+2.xlsx" Then
            Set wsTarget = Sheets("Forecast - Month +2")
        Else
            bError = True
        End If

        ' execute
        If bError Then
             MsgBox c.Value & " not recognized", vbExclamation, "Row " & c.Row
        Else
             tbl.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
             With wsTarget
                ' loop through the src/tgt ranges
                For i = 0 To UBound(arSrc)
                    'CZ data input/output
                    .Range(arTgt(i) & "34").Resize(6).Value2 = wsSrc.Range(arSrc(i) & "7").Resize(6).Value2
                    .Range(arTgt(i) & "34").Resize(6).NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
                    'SK data input/output
                    .Range(arTgt(i) & "55").Resize(6).Value2 = wsSrc.Range(arSrc(i) & "13").Resize(6).Value2
                    .Range(arTgt(i) & "55").Resize(6).NumberFormat = "#,##0,"
                Next
                ' zero values
                For i = 0 To UBound(arZeros)
                    .Range(arZeros(i) & "34").Resize(6).Value2 = 0
                    .Range(arZeros(i) & "55").Resize(6).Value2 = 0
                Next
            End With
            s = s & vbLf & wsTarget.Name ' for msgbox
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Sheets updated for " & s, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: With uncomment "'tbl.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False" works perfectly!
Thank you so much for brilliant solution!

Answer (score 0):

Will do a short mockup of what I described in my comment:

```
sub stuff()
    dim sourceSheet as worksheet
    set sourceSheet = Sheets("CZDataSource")
    dim destSheet as worksheet
    Select Case True
        Case sourceSheet.Cells(2,3).Value =  "RIG Forecast_2021_act.xlsx"
            set destSheet = Sheets("Forecast - Month")
        Case sourceSheet.Cells(2,3).Value =  "RIG Forecast_2021_m+1.xlsx"
            set destSheet = Sheets("Forecast - Month +1")
        Case sourceSheet.Cells(2,3).Value =  "RIG Forecast_2021_m+2.xlsx"
            set destSheet = Sheets("Forecast - Month +2")
    End Select
    Dim sourceRangeArray as variant
    sourceRangeArray = sourceSheet.Range("C7:C12") ', Keep filling these
    Dim destRangeArray as variant
    destRangeArray = destSheet.Range("AZ34:AZ39") ', Keep filling these
    Dim i as Long
    For i = lbound(sourceRangeArray) to ubound(sourceRangeArray) 
        DoTheThing sourceRangeArray(i),destRangeArray(i)
    Next i
End Sub

Private Sub DoTheThing(sourceRange as Range, destRange as Range)
    destRange.Value = sourceRange.Value
    destRange.Numberformat = "#,##0,"
End Sub
```

You continually use the same ranges, regardless of destination sheet, so you can have them 1:1 in the same order amongst the two arrays.

Changing to `.value = .value` will save you the copying and pasting, and removes the need for `pastespecial`; you would still keep the formatting, if it's necessary, though I have a feeling that you could format at the end over a larger range than inside of each operation... with the amount of ranges, it shouldn't be too terrible timewise to do as is.

The use of `Select` for your destination sheet removes the biggest chunk of what was occurring in your duplication of ranges, so that alone should save a huge chunk of time/repetition.

In looking at the ranges a little closer, the use of "1st" and "2nd" doesn't really seem to matter, since you're only looking at the name of a workbook in `C3`.  That would cut the `Select` down further.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but there is ByRef argument type mismatch for sourceRangeArray variable and I am not experienced with function to handle it. For C2 (1st and 2nd) there are slightly different actions when is set so it depends if there is set 1st or 2nd.